# after use generate_password_hash(password), password sequencethe is not in database

Tags: python, database, web

i am studying flask web, and  have some question

```
@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user=User(email=form.email.data,username=form.username.data, 
                  password_hash=form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('you can now login')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password) 

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<user %r>' % self.username
```

[register image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvkjs.jpg)

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkr7f.jpg)

When I enter the account password registration, the password is 16.
but The password of the database is also 16, not the sequence of the password.

i can't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
user=User(email=form.email.data,username=form.username.data, 
              password_hash=form.password.data)
```

Try this

```
user=User(email=form.email.data,username=form.username.data, 
              password=form.password.data)
```

Or if you want to be 100% sure then

```
user=User(email=form.email.data,username=form.username.data)
user.password = form.password.data
```

Comment: your idea is good, but i want to know why is my method  wrong.
this is link of the authon https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/8d/app/auth/views.py

Comment: Well, that's because in the User constructor, you put the password to the password_hash which is simple string instead of its setter

Comment: @kiudou your link does not set `password_hash` in the constructor. It does as Hanísek suggests. Which method do you expect to work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever calculate a hash in the register function. You just pass the form "password" value directly to the password_hash field.

Comment: The function of calculating the value of the cipher hash is realized by the only write attribute named password. When setting the value of this attribute, the assignment method calls the generate_password_hash () function provided by Werkzeug and assigns the result to the password_hash field. If you try to read the value of the password property, it returns an error because it is obvious that the original password can not be restored after the hash value is generated.
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/8d/app/auth/views.py

Comment: Yes but you *don't* set that attribute. Where do you think you do?